# How to delete keyframes in the armature

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

some keyframes are undeletable in dope sheet.
[image]

[image]

But, they can be deleted one by one in 3D view in object mode.....
This is annoying... How to delete all the keyframes at once?
[image]
[image]
The file is attached below:

[untitle.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxzqrrqknvg2av5/untitled.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Can you delete them in the graph editor instead?

Comment: The undeletable part are not shown in graph editor... I found this happen only when I added IK feet to the avatar....@Nathan

Comment: so what are those keyframes for, feet controllers? Please give more informations, or share your file

Comment: Probably, I am not sure. I don't know how to remove it at once. I only can remove it frame by frame in object mode in 3D view.... The file is attached... @moonboots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see on my screenshot, some bones have been assigned to some invisible layers, so, even if you can see that there are some active keyframes on the top horizontal tracks of your Dopesheet, you can't see what bones, nor delete those keyframes.

So you can either:

- Enable these layers to display those bones (in the 3D view) and their keyframes (in the Dopesheet)
- Click on the button *Include Channels From Objects/Bones That Are Not Visible* (phantom icon) on the horizontal menu on the bottom of your Dopesheet window to display these hidden keyframes in the Dopesheet

[image]